# Will upgrading my home electricity from 60A (120V) to 60A(240V) double my maximum available wattage?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage

My home appliances when turned on simultaneously runs at 3000 watt plus I am planning to move my gadgets from my office to my home (combination of multiple servers, multiple mac pcs and other gadget ) which will prolly need 7000 ~ 9000 watts if runned simultaneosly. Question is, if I upgrade my home service panel that supports 60A (120V) which means I can only have (5760 watts of electricity) to 60A (240V) , can I have 11520 watts for usage?

Comment: You can run a home on 240V but a house with 240V service and 120V outlets & lighting would be a criminally dangerous system and all loads would need to run on 240 including refrigerators, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> can I have 11520 watts for usage?

Yes, if it's evenly distributed across the two phases. Each phase can supply 60 A at 120 V (which I make 7.2 kW !). Neither phase may exceed 60 A, so if your loads are 'lumpy', you might not be able to achieve a balanced distribution.